# Symfony NotFoundHttpException don't throw my message

Tags: php, symfony

I try to throw a 404 exception with a specific message like that :

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException($error);
```

The problem is that it doesnt display the error message which is in the var $error. It display the message : Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) all error pages in application or create custom listener and inject custom response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a controller, try to use `throw $this->createNotFoundException($error);`

If you are in a service I think (in your case) you should create a [custom listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event) to the `kernel.exception` event.

Comment: I am not in controller i am in a service